# Flatten Combine publisher with an output of [String] to just String

Tags: swift, reactive, combine, publisher

I have a publisher that has an array as its output, I'd like to change it to shoot out just the value without the array.

```
// in a playground

import Combine

var subj = PassthroughSubject<[String], Never>()

subj.send(["1", "2", "3"])

// create publisher where Output == String
// if we did PublisherX(subj).eraseToAnyPublisher it'd 
// be of type AnyPublisher<String, Never> 
let cancel = PublisherX(subj).sink {
    // prints
    // "1"
    // "2"
    // "3"
    // rather than
    // ["1", "2", "3"]
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `flatMap` and `Array.publisher`:

```
var subj = PassthroughSubject<[String], Never>()

subj
  .flatMap(\.publisher)
  .sink {
    print($0)
  }

subj.send(["1", "2", "3"])
```

Comment: I should have you on speed dial for my Combine problems.

Comment: I have a new problem with catch terminating my publisher in this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74368156/catch-publisher-terminates-the-publisher